# How can i modify my panel

Tags: css, html

There is a panel:

[image]

I am working for an hour to get this panel done, can someone please help me or guide me how can I do this? I am using template to modify it, but not sure how to do it.

Here is the code until now:

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
/*@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');*/

body {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.8.0/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.8.0/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="panel panel-primary event-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading"><h2><a href="#">Title</a></h2></div>
        <div class="panel-body nopadding">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/400x150" alt="event image" class="img-responsive"/>
          <div class="row nopadding">
            <div class="col-sm-6 nopadding">
              <time class="start pink">
                Start <span class="day">20</span>
                <span class="month">Apr</span>
                <span class="year">2016</span>
              </time>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 nopadding">
              <time class="end purple">
                End <span class="day">20</span>
                <span class ="month">Apr</span>
                <span class="year">2016</span>
              </time>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer panel-primary">
          <p>Short description of event would go here.
          </p>
          <a href="http://ulurudaytours.com.au/" class="btn btn-success">Invest</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/edmbz4L2/

Comment: what did you try ? Do you have a piece of code already ?

Comment: Please show us the code that you have tried so far or better create a fiddle.

Comment: Step 1: You learn HTML. Step 2: You learn some CSS. Step 3: You code it yourself.

Comment: okay, copying my code in jsfiddle

Comment: Show your code *here*. A fiddle should only be added **on top** of the code you present in your question.

Comment: That is not your code. If you wrote that code, you wouldn't be asking this question here. It's way to complicated to be written by someone that doesn't know how to do something as simple as this.

Comment: @Derlin , check now

Comment: @icecub ofc i didnt wrote this code, i am using bootsnip template to modify it.

Comment: Then don't say Here is the code _i wrote_.

Comment: now ,see the edit

Comment: So, what is the problem, what would you like to get?

Comment: @codexy i want to create the card but couldn't make that one. Any clues?